# How to get number of duplicates count SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, duplicates

I have a table something like this:

```
declare @Product table  (ProductId int)

insert into @Product select 1155
insert into @Product select 1155  
insert into @Product select 1159 
insert into @Product select 1154  
insert into @Product select 1154  
insert into @Product select 1152 
insert into @Product select 1151
```

I need to assign its duplicate count to a variable

```
DECLARE @duplicateCount INT;
```

I wrote a query to check duplicates

```
SELECT COUNT(c.ProductId)
FROM @Product c
GROUP BY c.ProductId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This query returns the following output:

```
+------------------+
| (No column name) |
+------------------+
| 2                |
| 2                |
+------------------+
```

Instead of that, I need to set duplicate records count to `@duplicateCount`, as the above example count should be 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT @duplicateCount = COALESCE(SUM(cnt), 0)
FROM (SELECT count(c.ProductId) as cnt
      FROM @Product c
      GROUP BY c.ProductId
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) p
```

Comment: which return null when no dplucates, intead of that can I get 0 when no duplicates

Comment: @Gamma . . . Use `COALESCE()`.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CTE

```
;with cte(cnt) as
(
SELECT count(c.ProductId)
    FROM @Product c
GROUP BY c.ProductId
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
select isnull(sum(cnt),0) cnt from cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @duplicateCount INT

;WITH CTE(Cnt_PID) AS (
SELECT COUNT(C.PRODUCTID)
FROM @PRODUCT C
GROUP BY C.PRODUCTID
HAVING COUNT(C.PRODUCTID) > 1)

SELECT @duplicateCount=SUM(CNT_PID) FROM CTE

SELECT @duplicateCount AS DUPCNT
```

Hope this Query works fine for your case